# Dynamic routes on same level in Laravel 5.2 with different controllers

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5, routeparams

I have a `ProfileController` and a `CategoryController`.

I want to show the profiles of my users with the following route:

```
my.domain.com/firstname.lastname
my.domain.com/firstname2.lastname2
...
```

Just like Facebook is doing it. Therefore, I want to handle this within my `ProfileController` so I ended up with a route like this:

`Route::get('/{userSlug}', array('uses' => 'ProfileController@getProfile'));`

That is no problem and it works fine. But now I want to show my categories like this:

```
my.domain.com/category-1
my.domain.com/category-2
...
```

The problem is, that I would do the route like this: `Route::get('/{categorySlug}', array('uses' => 'CategoryController@getCategory'));` but this route is already used by the profile.

I know I can use just one controller and check there if the slug is a userSlug or a `categorySlug`, but I really want to separate the profile logic from the category logic into their own controllers.

What is best practice here?

Comment: Will your category slugs actually be "category-1" and "category-2" etc?

Comment: No, in fact it could be any text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your user routes will *always* be in the form of `/firstname.lastname`, you could try [Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints):

```
Route::get('/{userSlug}', array('uses' => 'ProfileController@getProfile'))
        ->where('name', '[a-z]+\.[a-z]+');
```

Then, follow that up with your catch-all category route. However, you'd be far better off to prefix your category URLs (like `/category/category-1`) instead.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I need. I did not know that I can do a "where" behind the route definition. I basically was searching for a way to get into the ProfileController, check if the slug is a profile slug and if not, return to the routes file and take the next matching route and reach the CategoryController. But it seems like this is not possible.